# Could not parse the remainder: ' store/css/960.css' from 'static store/css/960.css'

Tags: python, django

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>{{title}}</title>
<meta name="description" content="My Store" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static store/css/960.css %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static store/css/screen.css %}" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static store/css/color.css %}" media="screen" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="css" type="text/css" href="{% static store/css/ie.css %}" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static store/js/shoppica.js %}"></script>
```

Вообщем пишет что не может найти нужный шаблон по пути, однако я проверял путь и он точно верный, вот фото папки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал убирать, добавлять store/ к пути, менял названия папок, ничего не помогает

Вот еще views.py если поможет

```
from django.http import request, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'store/index.html', {'title': 'заголовок'})
```

Answer (score 0):

возьми в кавычки путь внутри тега статик

```
{% static "store/css/960.css" %}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло, перепроврял все по три раза и не заметил такой глупой ошибки